# R-square from rpart model

Tags: r, rpart

How can I extract the R-square from a fit [rpart](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/index.html) model?

`rsq.rpart(fit)`

plots the two graphs, but I simply want to extract the R-square value for the full tree.

I assume this is fairly obvious, but numerous searches didn't really lend anything useful.  Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The advantage of R is that most of the time you can easily access the source code. So in your case, start with

```
> rsq.rpart
```

(without parenthesis) to see what the function actually does. The $R^2$ values are obtained as

```
tmp <- printcp(fit)
rsq.val <- 1-tmp[,c(3,4)]
```

where for each row (aka, No. splits) we have the "apparent" and "relative" (wrt. cross-validation) statistics.

Comment: +1, pressed post the same second your answer appeared. I would add that for a full tree rsq.val[nrow(rsq.val),] is probably what OP wants.

Comment: @mpiktas Oups... Needless to say, your comment is very appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I am (obviously) new to R, and never once did I think to look at the function as you first mentioned.  I was trying something similar to your answer, but that is perfect! Thx